# Async.each not working with post to database

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

```
var async = require('async');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var fs = require("fs");
var Item = require('../Item.Model');
var content = fs.readFileSync("sample.json");
var data = JSON.parse(content);

// createItemsToBeSaved
var updatePrices = function(data){
    async.each(hatstopurchase.pyroItems,function(hatNames,callback){
        var item = new Item();
        item.name = hatNames;
        item.bpPrice = data.response.items[hatNames].prices['6'].Tradable.Craftable[0].value;
        item.quantity_own = 0;
        item.limit = 1;
        item.last_updated = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
        item.save(function(err,result){
            console.log('beginning save');
            if(err){
                callback(err);
            }

            else{
                console.log('successfully posted');
                callback();
            }
        });  
    },function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }); 

}
updatePrices(data);
/////////// Item.Model.js file
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ItemSchema = new Schema({
name : String,
bpPrice : Number,
quantity_own : Number,
limit : Number,
last_updated : Number
```

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Item',ItemSchema);

Hey I was wondering if you guys can help me out. I've been trying to figure this out for awhile and with no luck. But the following code I am unable to post to the database. item.save method doesn't seem to do anything as I put console.log statements in there. I've been following this tutorial 
http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each
But it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you calling `mongoose.connect` to actually connect to the DB?

Comment: yes sorry I left that out.

Comment: mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/tf2-bot');

Comment: I'm an idiot. Answered my own question. Thank you JohnnyHK. I was using mongoose.createConnection instead of mongoose.connection. Now I have successfully posted to the database. I thought I was doing something wrong with async as its the first time I've ever used it. Thank you